# Create executable file of C/CPP programs

Tags: 16.04, programming

How to create executable file of c or cpp program which can be open by double click in ubuntu ??

Answer (score 0):

```
 chmod u+x <output file>
```

Or
     chmod +x output_file

Eg.

```
 chmod u+x ./a.out
```

Tip :Fat and ntfs partion wont support file permissions ,just copy the file to the home folder or desktop and try again

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the conversation that was taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45921/discussion-on-answer-by-minigeek-create-executable-file-of-c-cpp-programs).